# How do I enable Business API for a test user/business account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a Facebook business app that automates the process of uploading product catalogs for a business account.  I'm trying to prepare the app for review.  To do this I need to provide a test user that can demonstrate all of the API scopes I'm requesting, namely:

1. `business_management`
2. `catalog_management`

The whole workflow works with real users that have a role on my app.

For the test user (which is an admin of its own business account), everything works properly (Facebook login, granting permissions from the test user, getting the test user's list of businesses) up until the POST request that I make to create a catalog, using the business API endpoint `/v12.0/<test_business_ID>/owned_product_catalogs`.  The response I get is:

```
 Status:  400
 Response:
   {
     "error": {
       "message": "(#100) Missing Permission",
       "type": "OAuthException",
       "code": 100,
       "fbtrace_id": "*******"
     }
   }
```

The Graph API explorer gives this message for a GET request to `/<test_business_ID>/owned_product_catalogs` with the test user's token:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) This application has not been approved to use this API.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "*******"
  }
}
```

whereas if I substitute `<test_business_ID>` for my real business (that the app is associated with), the request is successful (I get an empty list).

I have tried a lot of things unsuccessfully to grant permission to my app on the test user's business:

- Removing the app from my real business and claiming it under the test business
- Inviting the test user to my real business
- Inviting the test business as a partner to my real business
- Inviting the real business as a partner to the test business

I've also read about sandbox accounts and system users, but I don't want to use a system user because I want any Facebook business admin to be able to connect my app to their business seamlessly through Facebook login.

How can I get the business API catalog endpoint working for a test user?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I am exactly in the same situation. Have you found some solution to this? Please tell me if you found something. @shortend

Comment: @makkasi: No solution.  Still the same error, and no idea how to get support from Facebook for this.  Very unfortunate as we may end up removing this feature from our software.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have wrote in their developers forum. Seems they are moving many of their support channels to forum. https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/2776000209200286/ This is what I have created